# MSDN link - site for explaining the API for SharePoint 2013 PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Just like the entire MSDN API for the SharePoint server side object model is available with classes, objects,methods and samples 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162979.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Similar this, Can i get the API  methods, classes for `PowerShell` with SPSite, SPWeb, SPGroup,SPList, SPDocumentLibrary objects and its associated methods?
Is there any msdn site exists, can anyone post the link here?

Comment: Want to make this as a community question *** . But am unable to see the community checkbox. pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft publishes [Use Windows PowerShell to administer SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is the reference for SharePoint cmdlets. That said, the SSOM API is identical, should you need to create new objects manually. For example, here's a PowerShell script that mixes native cmdlets and the SSOM API directly.

```
$site = (Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | ?{$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication -eq $true}).Sites[0]
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profiles = $upm.GetEnumerator()
```

And as another example, here's one that performs reflection (reflection is not supported by the SharePoint PG) using PowerShell.

```
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.Name -eq "User Profile Service Application"}

$propData = $upa.GetType().GetProperties([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic)

$socialProp = $propData | where {$_.Name -eq "SocialDatabase"}
$socialProp.GetValue($upa)

$profileProp = $propData | where {$_.Name -eq "ProfileDatabase"}
$profileProp.GetValue($upa)

$syncProp = $propData | where {$_.Name -eq "SynchronizationData"}
$syncProp.GetValue($upa)
```

Comment: Trevor, I have a requirement to fetch a speicif property of a SPGroup and set that property accordingly.since he num of groups are huge, i cant do that change manually  so i thought of writing the powershell script. but i am unable to get the property of that spgroup object. like" who can view the membership of the group" . i have written the C# + SSOM , for implementing this, but when i thought of doing this using powershell , am not knowing, what will be the properties of this spobject. in my powershll ISE , there is no intellisense , so i cant assume as well. thats the issue.

Comment: The properties are the same on the objects. For PowerShell, you would get the specific `SPSite.RootWeb.SiteGroups` object you want, then just example the `OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership` property. If it is `false`, then everyone who has access to the site can see the membership of the group.

Comment: your suggestion and valuable PS code helped me to write the script. :-)